# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to concatenate some files side by side.

I use the `pr` command in the terminal. It works well, but when I use it in a shell script, I get the following error message:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
myfile1=toto1.dat
myfile1=toto2.dat
file_out=mytoto_out.dat
touch ${file_out}
/usr/bin/pr -mts' ' <( /usr/bin/cut -d' ' -s -f1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 ${myfile1}) <( /usr/bin/cut -d' ' -s -f8 $myfile2) >>${file_out}
echo ${file_out} " is done"
```

Comment: Please show us the shell script that fails and not the command that works.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error for me. What shell are you using? `echo $SHELL`

Comment: #!/bin/sh

myfile1=toto1.dat
myfile1=toto2.dat
file_out=mytoto_out.dat

touch ${file_out}

  /usr/bin/pr -mts' ' <( /usr/bin/cut -d' ' -s -f1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 ${myfile1}) <( /usr/bin/cut -d' ' -s -f8 $myfile2) >>${file_out}

echo ${file_out} " is done"

Answer (score 12):

On the command line, your shell is bash. In your script you're using `/bin/sh`. `/bin/sh` apparently is not bash on your system, and the `<()` syntax is apparently not present in whatever shell `/bin/sh` is.

Change the shebang (the `#!/bin/sh` part) to `#!/bin/bash`.